# URL rewriting using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I want to customize my URL rewriting but it seems not working as I'd like it to.

My old code :

```
var rewrite = require('express-urlrewrite');

exports.rewrite = function(app){
  app.use(rewrite('/p/:id/:seoUrl', '/page/show/$1/$2'));
}
```

In my browser : http://mysite/p/1/seo-title (this URL works)

My new code :

```
var rewrite = require('express-urlrewrite');

exports.rewrite = function(app){
  app.use(rewrite('/:seoUrl', '/page/show/$1/$2'));
}
```

In my browser : http://mysite/seo-title (ID not found)

Using NodeJS, is there a way to exclude the ID in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

well. if you take a close look at this: `'/page/show/$1/$2'` you might notice that it accepts two arguments.

since you removed `:id` you'd have to replace `$1` with a static id or remove it completely aswell as you have to change `$2` to `$1`

so in the end your code might look like this: `app.use(rewrite('/:seoUrl', '/page/show/1/$1'));`

or like this: `app.use(rewrite('/:seoUrl', '/page/show/$1'));`

Comment: Yes I know that, but using NodeJS is there a way to custom url and remove ID? `:seoUrl` is the formatted URL but I also need the ID to show the page...

Comment: @tonymx227 ok so you did not read my text after i added two examples. take a second look.

Comment: I read your second example but it send `:seoUrl` but not `:id`. I'd like to send `:id` but not to show `ID` in the url...

Comment: @tonymx227 you were asking for `:id` to be removed from the route. if you still need the id internally you should use the first example and change 1 to the page id you want to refer to.

Comment: Ok but the page Id I want to refer to is dynamic... It depends on the page. The user can choose the page he wants to show...

Comment: @tonymx227 then your question is rated unclear and violates SO's question rules. if you want to keep the id, why do you remove it in the first place?

Comment: Because I want a better seo url, `http://mysite.fr/my-page` is better than `http://mysite.fr/p/1/my-page`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92065/discussion-between-gottz-and-tonymx227).